# Поиск на сайте

Tags: поиск, kohana

Как лучше всего организовать поиск на kohana-сайте (новостной сайт)? Поставить сторонний поисковой движок? или как?

Answer (score 1):

Как всегда, есть варианты:

1. Использовать сторонний поиск (Google, Yandex etc)
2. Написать свой, матёрый с мадмуазелями и преферансом.

Если у вас новости с тегами, грамотно организована БД, то и свой вполне справится.